# FileNotFoundException on report or export to excel in Java Web Start/browser

Tags: java, jnlp, filenotfoundexception

If I run JNLP of a web start app. in folder dist, then I'm not to see this error.

But when I to run in browser, error report it happened like this in my JNLP program. I have attempted everything in my power to fix it, but still cannot mitigate this problem.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREXception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\id\ptmsa\co\id\report\TestReport.jasper
```

Comment: Show the code you use to call the report generation.

Comment: String path = "src/id/ptmsa/co/id/report/TesReport.jasper";    
  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Direktori " + path );            
            
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path, null, koneksi);
System.out.println("Viewing...");
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);  
System.out.println("Done!");